# Does the preservation fluid (ethanol or formaldehyde) leach heavy metals from mollusc tissue?

Tags: zoology, ecology, lab-techniques, methods, lab-reagents

In a thread on researchgate, the concern was raised that long term exposure to unbuffered preservation fluids such as ethanol or formaldehyde may leach heavy metals from biological samples due to a reduction in the fluid's pH. Can anybody tell me if this also applies to mollusc samples? I would assume that carbonate shells function as a pH buffer and thus keep the fluid's pH relatively stable over a long time.

Edit: [Link to the researchgate thread](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Do_the_preservation_chemicals_affect_heavy_metal_concentrations_in_tissues_of_preserved_specimens). No research articles were mentioned in that thread.